# Laravel: Any way to load a blade template without compiling it?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

We have a situation where we'd like to load a blade template when we send an email and store that blade template without compiling it inside the database.  The use case here is that we want to be able to go back and send an email with the original template in case it changes in the future.

So in the resend of the email, we'd want to use the template as it was when the email was first sent.  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Saving a whole blade template in the DB seems overkill to me, because the same template will be repeated many times.

If you really need to do this, in my opinion you should use a different file with a different for every template "version" and in the DB you can just save the file name at that time.